# Duplicate of website - subsite Worpress Multisite - Front-end registration

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I want that when new user register on my wp multisite (front-end), new subsite that is a duplicate of premade website is created. By default empty website is created. I found plugin that creates duplicate - the way i want, but from backend - me. I want that duplicate is auto created when user register on front-end. Is there any plugin (free or pro) to do that? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Checkout the post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282330/create-new-site-subsite-in-wordpress-multisite-by-subscriber-user-instead-of-net as it of similar question if may be of help

Comment: No, cuz i need a duplicate like i said, not just an empty website.